# nginx and trailing slash with proxy pass

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using the following configuration for nginx 1.4.1:

```
server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  correct.name.gr;

    location /test/register {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is when the users vist `http://correct.name.gr:8000/test/register/` they should be proxied to the apache which runs on port 80.

When I visit `http://correct.name.gr:8000/test/register/` I get correct results (index.php).
When I visit `http://correct.name.gr:8000/test/register/asd` I get correct results (404 from apache).
When I visit `http://correct.name.gr:8000/test/asd` I get correct results (404 from nginx).
When I visit `http://correct.name.gr:8000/test/register123` I get correct results (404 from apache).

**The problem is when I visit `http://correct.name.gr:8000/test/register`. I get a 301 response and I am redirected to `http://localhost/test/register/` (notice the trailing slash and of course the 'localhost')!!!**

I haven't done any other configurations to nginx to put trailing slashes or something similar. Do you know what is the problem ? I want `http://correct.name.gr:8000/test/register` to work correctly by proxying to apache (or if not possible at least to issue a 404 error and not a redirect to the localhost of the user).

**Update 1**: I tried `http://correct.name.gr:8000/test/register` from a different computer than the one with which I had the bad behavior yesterday.. Well, it worked: I just got a 301 response that pointed me to the correct `http://correct.name.gr:8000/test/register/`! How is it possible to work from one computer  but not from the other (I'm using the same browser-Chrome in both computers)? I will try again tomorrow to test from a third one to see the behavior.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your upstream server (either apache or your script) triggered a redirect to the **absolute** url `http://localhost/test/register/`. Because you use `http://127.0.0.1` in your `proxy_pass` directive, nginx doesn't find a match of the domain name and returns the `Location` header as is.

I think the right solution is to NOT use absolute redirect if the redirect is to an internal url.  This is always a good practice.

However, without changing upstream server, there are two quick solutions.

you can use

```
proxy_pass http://localhost;
```

This will tell nginx the domain name of upstream is `localhost`. Then nginx will know to replace `http://localhost` by `http://correct.name.gr:8000` when it finds that part in the `Location` header from upstream.

Another one is to add a `proxy_redirect` line to force nginx to rewrite any location header with `http://localhost/` in it.

```
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
 proxy_redirect http://localhost/ /;
```

I prefer to the first solution because it's simpler. There is no DNS lookup overhead of using `proxy_pass http://localhost;` because nginx does the lookup in advance when it starts the web server.

reference: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try playing with [server_name_in_redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name_in_redirect)?

However, I found you question via google because I run the same issue with the trailing slash. Nginx forces a 301 to the same URL *with* an trailing slash.

Comment: No I did not try playing with that... I will tomorrow - however take a look at the update pls

Comment: Just to avoid any browser caching side effects, I would rather recommend testing these redirects with curl from a shell: "curl -IL http://correct.name.gr:8000/test/register"

Comment: Yes, very nice comment... Curl FTW !