# nginx with Etherpad in a subdirectory

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, etherpad

I am setting up etherpad-lite in a subdirectory at [this location](https://whitewaterwriters.com/etherpad).

Unfortunately the files in 'static' aren't being loaded:

[image]

Clearly something is going on in my nginx, which (partially) looks like this:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }
    
    
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  www.whitewaterwriters.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.whitewaterwriters.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.whitewaterwriters.com/privkey.pem;
    return 301 https://whitewaterwriters.com$request_uri;
}
    
server {
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name whitewaterwriters.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/whitewaterwriters.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/whitewaterwriters.com/privkey.pem;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.php;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}


    location ~/watchtower/.*/live/pdfs/ {
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /watchtower {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    }


 location /etherpad {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }
  
    location /{
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/whitewaterwriters-site/_site/;
    }


        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

My question is: how do I configure nginx so that the missing files appear?

There are some other questions on this topic both in the github issues and SE, but they, in general, are solved by moving from etherpad to etherpad-lite, which I already use, or are both unanswered and approaching a decade old...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: if you add a trailing slash to your prefixed location, everything would work as expected.

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    ''      close;
    default upgrade;
}
server {
    ...
    location /etherpad/ {
        proxy_buffering off; # recommended by etherpad nginx hosting examples
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # optional headers
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # EP logs to show the actual remote IP
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # for EP to set secure cookie flag when https is used
        # recommended with keepalive connections
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # WebSocket support
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        # upstream
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    }
}
```

If you want `/etherpad` URI to work too, add the following location if you won't get HTTP 301 redirect from `/etherpad` to `/etherpad/` with the above configuration:

```
    location = /etherpad {
        return 301 /etherpad/;
    }
```

For me it wasn't necessary, but it can depend on your server environment.

To preserve query string, if any, you can use `return 301 /etherpad/$is_args$args;` or `rewrite ^ /etherpad/ permanent` instead.

---

Long answer (and what happened undercover).

There are many question on SO about *"how can I host a webapp under an URI prefix"*. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840133/7121513) is one on my answers and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/932628/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy) is a ServerFault thread on the similar topic.

*The only right way to do it is to made your proxied app request its assets via relative URIs only (consider `assets/script.js` instead of `/assets/script.js`) or using the right URI prefix (`/etherpad/assets/script.js`).*

Luckily, etherpad requests its assets using a relative paths (e.g. `<script src="static/js/index.js"></script>`) making it suitable to be hosted under any URI prefix. The problem is, when your origin URI is `/etherpad`, browser considers the current remote web server directory as the root one, and requests above script from server as `scheme://domain/static/js/index.js`. That request won't even caught by your `location /etherpad { ... }` (since it isn't starts with `/etherpad`). On the other hand, when your origin URI is `/etherpad/`, browser considers the current remote web server directory as the `/etherpad/` and correctly requests above script from server as `scheme://domain/etherpad/static/js/index.js`.

Now let's see what happened with the proxied request `/etherpad/<path>` using your original configuration. Since you are using a trailing slash after the upstream address (`http://localhost` + `/`), nginx cut the location `/etherpad` prefix from the request URI and prepend it with that slash (or any other URI used in a `proxy_pass` directive after the upstream name) resulting in `//<path>`. You can read [A little confused about trailing slash behavior in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx) or [nginx and trailing slash with proxy pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422558/nginx-and-trailing-slash-with-proxy-pass) SO threads for more details. Anyway that URI won't served by etherpad giving you `Cannot GET //<path>` error.

Changing `location /etherpad { ... }` to the `location /etherpad/ { ... }` you'll made both of the aforementioned problems gone.

---

A few words about the etherpad [wiki](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-put-Etherpad-Lite-behind-a-reverse-Proxy) examples, especially [this one](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-put-Etherpad-Lite-behind-a-reverse-Proxy#from-subdirectory-url).

Both

```
location /etherpad/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/;
    ...
}
```

and

```
location /etherpad/ {
    rewrite ^/etherpad(/.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
    ...
}
```

do the same string - stripping the `/etherpad` prefix from the request URI before passing it to the upstream. However the first one do it in a much more efficient way. It is a good practice to avoid regular expressions whenever possible. Using

```
location = /etherpad {
    return 301 /etherpad/;
}
```

is also more efficient than

```
rewrite ^/etherpad$ /etherpad/ permanent;
```

Second and third location blocks from the above wiki example completely duplicate functionality from the first one. Moreover, that example breaks [WebSocket support](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) (whoever wrote it, he can at least add that support to the `location /pad/socket.io { ... }` block).

And never do the thing used at [this](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-put-Etherpad-Lite-behind-a-reverse-Proxy#hosted-at--with-friendly-urls-for-pads) example:

```
location ~ ^/$ { ... }
```

Use exact matching location instead:

```
location = / { ... }
```

---

Here is one more configuration I've tested in order to check if I can serve etherpad static assets directly via nginx. It seems to be workable, although I didn't tested it a lot. It uses an uncompressed js/css assets versions (which should not impact performance when you are using gzip or some other compression). It is also a good example of a configuration where you can't avoid using `rewrite` directive to strip a prefix from the request URI.

```
    location /etherpad/static/ {
        # trying to serve assets directly via nginx
        # if the asset is not found, pass the request to the nodejs upstream
        rewrite ^/etherpad(/.*) $1 break;
        root /full/path/to/etherpad-lite/src;
        try_files $uri @etherpad;
    }
    location /etherpad/ {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    }
    location @etherpad {
        proxy_redirect / /etherpad/;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
```

**Update**

As being [suggested](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/issues/5359#issuecomment-1017555489) on the GitHub, URIs started with `/etherpad/static/plugins/` prefix should always be passed to the nodejs upstream since there are no corresponding assets would exists under the `/path/to/etherpad/src/static/` directory. Despite there is already defined fallback to the nodejs upstream (`try_files $uri @etherpad`), to eliminate an extra `stat` system call produced by the `try_files` directive we can modify the above configuration to this one:

```
    location ~ ^/etherpad/static/(?!plugins/) {
        # trying to serve assets directly via nginx
        # if the asset is not found, pass the request to the nodejs upstream
        rewrite ^/etherpad(/.*) $1 break;
        root /full/path/to/etherpad-lite/src;
        try_files $uri @etherpad;
    }
    location /etherpad/ {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    }
    location @etherpad {
        proxy_redirect / /etherpad/;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
```

(using negative lookahead regex, better readability) or to this one:

```
    location /etherpad/ {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    }
    location /etherpad/static/ {
        rewrite ^/etherpad(/.*) $1 break;
        root /full/path/to/etherpad-lite/src;
        try_files $uri @etherpad;
    }
    location /etherpad/static/plugins/ {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/static/plugins/;
    }
    location @etherpad {
        proxy_redirect / /etherpad/;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
```

(only prefix locations, better performance). The repetitive part

```
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

and probably other optional headers (`X-Real-IP`, `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto`) setup mentioned at the very beginning of the answer, can be used as a separate file, e.g. `etherpad-proxy.conf`, and included into the main nginx config with the [`include`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to navigate the static content to the correct folder with:

```
location /static {
     root root /usr/share/nginx/html/whitewaterwriters-site/_site/static;
}

# or something like:

location /etherpad/static {
     root root /usr/share/nginx/html/whitewaterwriters-site/_site/;
}
```

since this is working: https://whitewaterwriters.com/etherpad/static/js/vendors/html10n.js?v=869d568c

Comment: It's a senible approach I think  - but I'm just lost in a maze of it not quite working...

Comment: your application is looking for /static/ at the root, without the /etherpad/. I just suggested to reroute it to the correct location. What are you lost in?